# How can I backup or move my Time Machine data on my non-repairable (but readable) volume to another disk?

Tags: macos, time-machine, filesystem-corruption

Trying to repair my disk results in the following:

```
Verifying volume “Drobo”
Checking file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
Invalid sibling link
The volume Drobo was found corrupt and needs to be repaired.
Error: This disk needs to be repaired. Click Repair Disk.

Verify and Repair volume “Drobo”
Checking file system
Checking Journaled HFS Plus volume.
Checking extents overflow file.
Checking catalog file.
Invalid sibling link
Rebuilding catalog B-tree.
The volume Drobo could not be repaired.
Volume repair complete.
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.
```

As you may have guessed, this disk is on a Drobo unit. The Drobo utilities indicate that everything is okay with the physical drives.

The problem is this disk has Time Machine backup data on it. I was thinking of using SuperDuper! to make a disk image of it but I'm not sure how that will turn out since there is Time Machine data involved and rather than risking it I figured I would ask first.

I can mount the disk but it mounts as read-only.

How can I (preferably) backup (or move) my Time Machine data on this non-repariable volume to another one so I can format the non-repairable volume and use it again? Will SuperDuper! work for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not able to mount the disk, what you're requesting is not possible or at least very hard.

You can try tools like [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/) to carry on where Disk Utility fails.

Once you are able to mount the disk, copy the Backups.backupdb folder to a new disk. Ignore files that fail, it's only a backup after all… You'll be able to open the backups from the new disk using the Time Machine application and telling it to use a different disk.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned I can mount the disk. It does mount as read-only though.

Comment: Excellent. Copy the data and you're golden.

Comment: Tried a straight copy, didn't work out well. Time Machine doesn't recognize the new disk.

Comment: Did some searching and looks like a block copy method needs to be used. This blog post has a decent straightforward description. http://rolfje.wordpress.com/2008/09/07/a-bigger-timemachine-without-changing-history/ Those instructions cater to moving your backups to a larger drive, but serve this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a function within Drobo called Dobo Copy.  It makes a full copy of itself where you want it.  As long as you have enough storage to copy it.  But if your system is working well and do not new the backed up files, just start anew.  Drobo usually fixes itself but you said that Drobo lyons the drive ok.  Do you have multiple partitions and how did you format the drive.  With diskutil or with Drobo.  Drobo usually does a good job.  Do you still have free slots or or bigger drive to replace a failing drive.  Be careful with shutting drove off follow the sequence of the manual. Make site it is at the least in standby mode.

Comment: Drobo Copy doesn't do a block level copy.